# Using 3 channel image in numpy as texture image in vtk

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I have a RGB image in numpy format that I want to using for texture mapping using vtk. I usually load the texture image using `PNGReader` as should below --

```
png_reader = vtk.vtkPNGReader()
png_reader.SetFileName(png_file) 
texture.SetInputConnection(png_reader.GetOutputPort())
```

I know vtk provides some sort of python integration but I wasn't sure how to do it.

EDIT -- I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395269/numpy-uint8-t-arrays-to-vtkimagedata), but that solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy uint8\_t arrays to vtkImageData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395269/numpy-uint8-t-arrays-to-vtkimagedata)

Comment: Yup I had tried that. That solution does not work. e.g. the function `SetSpacing` takes a tuple of size 3 instead to 2. Also, it gives an error `3D texture maps currently are not supported!`. So, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: what is the numpy format? if it is .npy - load it as a numpy object and then use ``vtk.util.numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image is `nx` by `ny` by 3 in a NumPy array, you could create a `vtkImageData` object and pass that to a `vtkTexture` object (this is would be the same workflow you have, just skipping the reader):

```py
import vtk
from vtk.util.numpy_support import numpy_to_vtk
import numpy as np

# Assuming you have a 3D NumPy array as `image`:
image = np.random.randn(2048, 1024, 3)

grid = vtk.vtkImageData()
grid.SetDimensions(image.shape[1], image.shape[0], 1)
vtkarr = numpy_to_vtk(np.flip(image.swapaxes(0,1), axis=1).reshape((-1, 3), order='F'))
vtkarr.SetName('Image')
grid.GetPointData().AddArray(vtkarr)
grid.GetPointData().SetActiveScalars('Image')

vtex = vtk.vtkTexture()
vtex.SetInputDataObject(grid)
vtex.Update()
```

***Note:*** there are some convenience methods coming to [PyVista](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/) to make this even easier:

```py
import pyvista
texture = pyvista.numpy_to_texture(image)
```